# Can I cast m3u files to Chromecast?

Tags: ios, avplayer, google-cast, m3u8, avplayerviewcontroller

is it possible to cast m3u8 file.? I am using avplayer. In google cast site they mentioned that it only support formats : -
AAC
MP3
MP4
WAV
WebM

link : https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/media

If m3u8 is supporting, how can I implement it programatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

m3u8 playlists are supported. You can read the docs; there is not much difference between casting an mp4 or m3u8; you may need to make sure CORS headers are sent from the content server. To see an example, look at the official sample [CastVideos-android](https://github.com/googlecast/CastVideos-android) sample that can play such content.